# Adding a constant integer to a value in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How would you add a constant number, say 1, to a value in a dictionary if certain conditions are fulfilled.

For example, if I had a dictionary:

```
dict = {'0':3, '1':3, '2':4, '3':4, '4':4}
```

If I simply wanted to add the integer 1 to every value in the dictionary so it updates dict as this:

```
dict = {'0':4, '1':4, '2':5, '3':5, '4':5}
```

When I used the following code where the Cur_FID is the first one in the dictionary '0', it gave me a value of 5?  It should have given me 4.  ??

```
for lucodes in gridList2:   # a list of the values [3,3,4,4,4] -- have to separate out because it's part of a larger nested list
    if lucodes > 1:
        if lucodes < 5:
            FID_GC_dict[Cur_FID] = lucodes + 1

print FID_GC_dict[Cur_FID]   #returned 5??? weird
```

I want to add 1 to all the values, but stopped here when the first dictionary update did something weird.

Comment: You can write your comparison as `if 1 < lucodes < 5:`

Comment: Thanks...I will shorten it up.

Comment: I think that you need to post code concerning where you set/change `Cur_FID`. I have a feeling that it's being used twice for updates in `FID_GC_dict`

Comment: Ok, I'm going to repost the whole code so it makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to use a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object, which you can use in every way like a normal dictionary in most ways but it is optimized for keeping a count of items:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = Counter({'0':3, '1':3, '2':4, '3':4, '4':4})
>>> d
Counter({'3': 4, '2': 4, '4': 4, '1': 3, '0': 3})
>>> d.update(d.keys())
>>> d
Counter({'3': 5, '2': 5, '4': 5, '1': 4, '0': 4})
```

As for only doing it when certain conditions are fulfilled, just use a comprehension or generator to only pass the list of the keys you want to increment to `d.update()`:

```
>>> d = Counter({'3': 4, '2': 4, '4': 4, '1': 3, '0': 3})
>>> d.update((k for k, v in d.items() if v == 4))
>>> d
Counter({'3': 5, '2': 5, '4': 5, '1': 3, '0': 3})
```

Comment: But what if the dictionary is huge and I only want to update the key:values for the ones listed in gridList2?  How would I handle that?

Comment: @Linda - Is `gridList2` a list of keys, a list of key/value tuples, or a list of values?

Comment: It's a list of values corresponding to an adjacent neighbors matrix.  I have a dictionary (the one I'm trying to update).  I also have a nested list of adjacent neighbors.  I use the dictionary to populate the nested gridList2 based on nested neighbor list.  If certain conditions, apply I want to update the dictionary only corresponding to the nested gridList2.  Make sense?

Comment: @Linda - Not really, dictionaries are unordered so it will be difficult to associate a list of values with a specific set of key/value pairs.  If instead you could populate `gridList2` with lists of keys then it would simplify things a lot.

Comment: As far as adding 1 to every value in the dictionary, if that's what you want to do....I think this answer is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this would be to use the items() method of dictionary which returns a list of key, value tuples:

```
def f(dict):
    for entry in dict.items():
        if entry[1] > 1 and entry[1] < 5:
            dict[entry[0]] = entry[1] + 1
    return dict
```

You can then extend this to take an arbitrary function:

```
def f(dict, func):
    for entry in dict.items():
        if func(entry[1]):
            dict[entry[0]] = entry[1] + 1
    return dict
```

This can be provided a function such as:

```
def is_greater_than_one(x):
    return x > 1
```

and called in the following way:

```
f(input_dictionary,is_greater_than_one)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I think I asked it too simply?  What if the dictionary is quite large and I only wanted to update the 4 items in the dictionary based on the conditions met when processing gridList2?  I don't want to update every single item in the dictionary, just a select few.  I know I wasn't clear in asking my initial question.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code says the following:

```
for each value in [3,3,4,4,4]:
    if 1 < value < 5:
        FID_thingy['0'] = value + 1
```

So it will set `FID_thingy['0']` to 4 then 4 then 5 then 5 then 5. Do you see why?

Comment: Because it goes through each value in the list for just the one FID_thingy key.  I get it...not sure how to fix it though.