# Updating a dictionary by adding the integer 1 to a select few values in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a constant integer to a value in a python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623836/adding-a-constant-integer-to-a-value-in-a-python-dictionary)

The is a report because I wasn't very clear on asking my question previously.  I am doing a cellular automata code where I have made a dictionary of a arcgis shapefile FID's and Land Use Codes.  FIDs are the point or cell id.  I also have created a nested list of each point's adjacent neighbors.  Currently I'm looking for clusters of like land use codes by doing a cluster analysis in arcgis.  I created a dictionary for each FID and whether it is clustered, which is either 'None' or 'HH'.  What the code will do is for each point is give me the cluster code of the point's adjacent neighbors.  If all the values in the list have an 'HH', then I want to go get the land use codes from the FID/LandUse dictionary.  I then want to add an integer 1 to each land use code within the gridList2 and update the FID/LandUse dictionary, but only if the land use codes are between 1 and 5.  So I'm not updating every value in the FID/LandUse dictionary, just the ones corresponding to gridList2.  The code I've written isn't working because I'm apparently iterating over the entire gridList when I'm adding 1 for just one dictionary key.

Here's the code:

```
import arcpy, string, csv

#Creating a dictionary of FID: LU_Codes from external txt file
text_file = open("H:\SWAT\NC\FID_Whole_Copy.txt", "rb")
FID_GC_dict =  {}
reader = csv.reader(text_file, delimiter='\t')
for line in reader:
    FID_GC_dict[line[0]] = int(line[1])
text_file.close()


#Importing neighbor list file for each FID value
Neighbors_file = open("H:\SWAT\NC\Pro_NL_Copy.txt","rb")
Entries = Neighbors_file.readlines()
Neighbors_file.close()
Neighbors_List = map(string.split, Entries)

#creates a list of the current FID
FID = [x[0] for x in Neighbors_List]
#print FID

Cluster_dict = {}
sc1 = arcpy.SearchCursor('H:\\SWAT\\NC\\cluster.shp')
for row in sc1:
    Cluster_dict[str(row.FID)] = [row.COType]

for k, v in Cluster_dict.iteritems():
    if v == [u' ']:
        Cluster_dict[k] = 'None'
    if v == [u'HH']:
        Cluster_dict[k] = 'HH'

#print Cluster_dict
i = iter(FID)   
Cur_FID = i.next()

clusterList = []
for clist in Neighbors_List:
    if clist[0] == Cur_FID:
        for ccodes in clist:
            clusterList.append(Cluster_dict[ccodes])
print clusterList
numtot = len(clusterList)
noc = clusterList.count('HH')
diff = numtot - noc
print diff
if diff == 0:
    gridList2 = []
    for nlist in Neighbors_List:
        if nlist[0] == Cur_FID:
            for neighbors in nlist:
                gridList2.append(FID_GC_dict[neighbors])
print gridList2
for lucodes in gridList2:
    if lucodes > 1:   #I haven't condensed these two lines of code yet.
        if lucodes < 5:
            FID_GC_dict[Cur_FID] = lucodes + 1   #This gives me a value of 5...should be 4, see below.

print FID_GC_dict[Cur_FID]
```

So if the first FID is '0', the neighbors list will be ['0','1','12','13','14'].  All values have an 'HH', so I want to get the land use codes from the FID/Landuse dictionary which are: [3,3,4,4,4].  Then I want to add 1 to the gridList2 (which is unmutable I've discovered) and update FID/LandUSE dictionary.

Comment: This is the densest question I've seen, and although I *think* I follow you, it would help if you could break it up into several sections. I'd segment it into a data structure representation, step by step desired implementation, and what you think is going wrong (you briefly touch on this, but a more concrete example would be excellent).

Comment: Ok, I'm new to Stack Overflow...I will edit the initial question from now on...sorry about that.

Comment: Also, I think I may have worked it out in my head.  Instead of updating all the FID/LandUse dictionary entries for each gridList2 value, I will just update the current FID land use code.  I'm going to the next FID anyway so my current method would add 1 twice to some of the neighbors.